How can I get Vim to nag me into improving?
I would like to improve my ability to learn Vim by making it tell me when I missed an opportunity. How can I achieve this?
If I pressed l 10 times, and then did something else, it might pop up to say "Hey, try 10l next time."
If I entered insert mode with i, then hit end to go to the end of the line and then enter, it'd say "Next time you want to start an empty new line after the cursor, just hit o from normal mode."
These are obviously very basic examples, but you get the idea.
(And FWIW, I've been vimming for years, and I know all the different ways to get to insert mode, but I still just about ALWAYS use i because I learnt it first and haven't put the effort in to build the muscle memory for the others)

Plugin requests are off-topic.

Yes, we get the idea: instead of learning your tool correctly you want some other tool to treat you like an idiot.

I'd argue I want both things, because I believe the second thing, which you make sound like a bad thing, will help with the first thing ‍♂️

No they're not, @Friedrich : https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

@Codemonkey that page says that questions about plugins are on-topic, but we have long held that requests for plugins are off: they are too much like shopping requests to be useful, and we generally have leaned on (3) from SO's on-topic page, though we've had our own recommendation convo (see also list questions).

It might be worth a [meta] conversation to decide whether to update our own guidance accordingly, or (re-)build consensus on these questions being on-/off-topic.

I have leaned towards re-framing questions: instead of "is there a plugin that X" I [edit] to ask "how can I accomplish X" (to which "use plugin Y by doing Z because of features A & B" is a perfectly acceptable answer!)

You could be interested to the hardtime.nvim plugin.
It:

Blocks repeated keys within a period of time
Prints hints about better commands e.g.: Use ci" instead of di"i
Reports your most common bad habits for improvement

Thanks to @ChristianBrabandt here are some Vim alternatives:

HardMode
MediumMode
Vim-HardMode


Perfect, thank you. See, that wasn't hard was it, @Friedrich

@Codemonkey Fixing a flat tire isn't hard either. Asking about it here would be just as off-topic as your question.

Thanks for the feedback! I'm happy we could help you :-)

Gna, Neovim only. What about one or two or three Vim plugins?
